# diffusion coefficient initial boundary data discontinuity

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I am looking at the diffusion equation $u_t=u_{xx},x\in [0,\pi]$ with zero on the boundaries and $f(x)=1$ as initial data. Clearly there is a discontinuity at $x=0,x=\pi$. So $f(x)$ can be represented as $$f(x)=\sum_{odd\;n}\frac{\sin(nx)}{\pi n},$$
there is notes I am reading and it states the series converges but does so very slowly, so what? I don't understand how does it affect the solution or numerical scheme to solve it? Is the effect analytical or numerical? I understand that regardless of what $f$ is, the inside the region function is nice and smooth. But I don't understand how is this particular example relevant for discussion of the existence and uniqueness of the heat equation solution? Why do I care about the convergence of the series for $f(x)$?

Comment: "the series converges but does so very slowly [...] I don't understand how does it affect the solution or numerical scheme to solve it?" who claims it does, your book?

Comment: no, possibly I am confusing items and state wrong claims, this is what I am thinking of it. I am basically trying to understand this case, if there is inconsistence data, so what?

Comment: I can't see any reason why this is important for the heat equation. The Fourier series for the solution u(x,t) has an additional exponential term in $n$, and converges extremely fast, regardless of $f$ (this is why solutions of the heat equation are smooth!).

Comment: @Jeff: this is for the inside of the domain, but if you want to have regularity up to the boundary?

Comment: Right, so you'll have regularity up to the boundary $x=0$ and $x=\pi$, provided $t$ is bounded away from zero. Since the initial data is discontinuous, you cannot expect regularity up to the boundary at $t=0$ anyway. I guess you can say the Fourier series for u(x,t) converges progressively slower as $t\to 0$, and this is why you loose regularity near $t=0$.

Comment: @Jeff: so convergence of series is equivalent to regularity? I thought of regularity to be able to differentiate, so as long as I can take derivatives of each term, the whole series is smooth, why do I care about the convergence of the total series?

Comment: @Medan The rate of decay of the Fourier coefficients of a function is intimately related to regularity. Any Fourier analysis book will cover this, or you can search for some notes online, such as these: http://www-m7.ma.tum.de/foswiki/pub/M7/Analysis/Fourier13/lecture9.pdf

Comment: @Jeff: ok, I see, so the point is perhaps that such $f$ has a slowly convergent series. But it does converge pointwise, correct, i.e. for any $x$ I can write $f$ to be equal to it is Fourier series? Or anywhere outside of small regions around corners?Clearly, due to Gibbs, there is a region around those discontinuous corners where the series for $f$ will oscillate, so I can't claim any type of convergence there.

Comment: @Medan: Yes the series for f converges pointwise everywhere, but due to Gibbs, it does not converge uniformly.

Comment: @Jeff: but the wiggles don't dampen ever close to $x=0$ so how can it converge for those $x$ that are very close to $0$?

Comment: @Medan: Yes, this is Gibbs Phenomenon. The truncated Fourier series always overshoots by a fixed amount, no matter how many terms you take. However, the location of the overshoot gets closer and closer to $x=0$. So if you fix any $x>0$, the wiggles are eventually to the left of $x$, and the series converges at $x$.

Comment: @Jeff: If the function $f(x)=1$ on an interval $[0,\pi]$, how this series can be a Fourier series for the function as if I plug in zero or $\pi$ I get series to be equal to 0, not 1. i thought the series is approximation of $f$ at each point, including the $0,\pi$ points.

Comment: @Medan The Fourier sine series is equivalent to performing an odd extension of the function and then computing the full Fourier series. So you are actually computing the Fourier series of the function $f(x)=-1$ for $x \in (-\pi,0)$, $f(x)=1$ for $x\in (0,\pi)$, $f(x)=-1$ for $x \in (\pi,2\pi)$, and so on. This discontinuity is the reason you see Gibbs phenomenon. The Fourier series splits the difference evenly at discontinuities, hence it converges to $f(0)=0$ and $f(\pi)=0$. If you used a Fourier cosine series, this corresponds to the even extension, and you would not have Gibbs phenomenon.

Comment: @Jeff: I don't know about Fourier series a lot. Do I need to have a full [0,2\pi] for \sin series and therefore extension is needed? so what if i define $f(x)$ on [0,2\pi] to be 1, would it change anything?

Comment: Then you won't have a sine series, you'll have a cosine series.

Comment: You might want to check out a reference on Fourier series and read the highlights. Any undergraduate PDE book (Strauss, Olver, Shearer), will have a good section on Fourier series.